# Configuring ALB in Existing Application

Tags: redirect, webserver, load-balancing, httpserver, loadbalancer

Currently have an application which comprises of a webserver and 2 appservers. If a user hits URL http://example.com/node1,it will send request to Appserver1
and if user hits http://example.com/node 2, request will be send to appserver2.

I am struck at a point where i want to integrate load balancer into existing application setup.
I have pointed my webserver domain(example.com) as a target group in load balancer.
Now if a user hits LB URL https://lbsetup.com it will redirect to webserver(http://example.com)

More curious to know if a user hit URL https://lbsetup.com/node1 will it send request to appserver1 and receive response back. Any sort of guidance will be more helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Expecting a guidance to take it forward